# FLUTTER How to implement Digest Authentification

Tags: http, authentication, flutter, digest-authentication

to implement a normal HTTP Request is very easy. But to implement a Digest Authentification I do not really know how to implement.

In the best case you can discribe it for Flutter but I do not mind if it is in another language.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

The Dart `HttpClient` supports digest. If you know the realm in advance, call `addCredentials` before making the request. If not, implement the `authenticate` callback which will pass the scheme and realm back to you. You should then call `addCredentials` from your implementation of the callback.

You can still use `package:http` with an `HttpClient`, by passing it in:

```
  HttpClient authenticatingClient = HttpClient();
  authenticatingClient.addCredentials(url, realm, credentials);
  http.Client client = http.IOClient(authenticatingClient);
```