# How to make Digest Authentication with http in Flutter?

Tags: http, flutter, dart, digest-authentication

I am trying to make an ApI request with Digest Authentication. I found an answer to the above question [FLUTTER How to implement Digest Authentification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022844/flutter-how-to-implement-digest-authentification) but it is not very clear. The docs for digest are very minimal.

Following is my code

```
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as io_client;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

try {
  HttpClient authenticatingClient = HttpClient();

  authenticatingClient.authenticate = (uri, scheme, realm) {

    authenticatingClient.addCredentials(
        uri,
        realm,
        HttpClientDigestCredentials(
            DIGEST_AUTH_USERNAME, DIGEST_AUTH_PASSWORD));

    return Future.value(true);
  };

  http.Client client = io_client.IOClient(authenticatingClient);

  final response = await client.post(LOGIN_URL, body: {
    "username": userName,
    "password": password,
    "user_group": 2
  }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    debugPrint(response.body);
    CurvesLoginModel curvesLoginModel = standardSerializers.deserializeWith(
        CurvesLoginModel.serializer, json.decode(response.body));
    return curvesLoginModel;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
} on TimeoutException catch (_) {

  return null;
} on SocketException catch (_) {

  return null;
}


}
```

But what is `realm` in `addCredentials`.

Also is this the way to implement `Digest Authentication` in `http` for `Flutter`?
As soon as I hit my endpoint I get the following error `Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm is an arbitrary string provided by the web server to help you decide which username to use, in case you have more than one. It's sort of analogous to domain. In one domain your username might be fbloggs, in another fredb. By telling you the realm/domain you know which to provide.

Your cast problem is caused by using the value 2 in the body. That must be a `Map<String, String>`, but you have provided an integer. Replace it with `2.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody wants to know how to make digest auth with http then it is as follows

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:convert/convert.dart';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart' as crypto;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DigestAuthClient extends http.BaseClient {
  DigestAuthClient(String username, String password, {inner})
      : _auth = DigestAuth(username, password),
        // ignore: prefer_if_null_operators
        _inner = inner == null ? http.Client() : inner;

  final http.Client _inner;
  final DigestAuth _auth;

  void _setAuthString(http.BaseRequest request) {
    request.headers['Authorization'] =
        _auth.getAuthString(request.method, request.url);
  }

  @override
  Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) async {
    final response = await _inner.send(request);

    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      final newRequest = copyRequest(request);
      final String authInfo = response.headers['www-authenticate'];
      _auth.initFromAuthorizationHeader(authInfo);

      _setAuthString(newRequest);

      return _inner.send(newRequest);
    }

    // we should reach this point only with errors other than 401
    return response;
  }
}

Map<String, String> splitAuthenticateHeader(String header) {
  if (header == null || !header.startsWith('Digest ')) {
    return null;
  }
  String token = header.substring(7); // remove 'Digest '

  var ret = <String, String>{};

  final components = token.split(',').map((token) => token.trim());
  for (final component in components) {
    final kv = component.split('=');
    ret[kv[0]] = kv.getRange(1, kv.length).join('=').replaceAll('"', '');
  }
  return ret;
}

String md5Hash(String data) {
  var content = const Utf8Encoder().convert(data);
  var md5 = crypto.md5;
  var digest = md5.convert(content).toString();
  return digest;
}

// from http_retry
/// Returns a copy of [original].
http.Request _copyNormalRequest(http.Request original) {
  var request = http.Request(original.method, original.url)
    ..followRedirects = original.followRedirects
    ..persistentConnection = original.persistentConnection
    ..body = original.body;
  request.headers.addAll(original.headers);
  request.maxRedirects = original.maxRedirects;

  return request;
}

http.BaseRequest copyRequest(http.BaseRequest original) {
  if (original is http.Request) {
    return _copyNormalRequest(original);
  } else {
    throw UnimplementedError(
        'cannot handle yet requests of type ${original.runtimeType}');
  }
}

// Digest auth

String _formatNonceCount(int nc) {
  return nc.toRadixString(16).padLeft(8, '0');
}

String _computeHA1(String realm, String algorithm, String username,
    String password, String nonce, String cnonce) {
  String ha1;

  if (algorithm == null || algorithm == 'MD5') {
    final token1 = "$username:$realm:$password";
    ha1 = md5Hash(token1);
  } else if (algorithm == 'MD5-sess') {
    final token1 = "$username:$realm:$password";
    final md51 = md5Hash(token1);
    final token2 = "$md51:$nonce:$cnonce";
    ha1 = md5Hash(token2);
  }

  return ha1;
}

Map<String, String> computeResponse(
    String method,
    String path,
    String body,
    String algorithm,
    String qop,
    String opaque,
    String realm,
    String cnonce,
    String nonce,
    int nc,
    String username,
    String password) {
  var ret = <String, String>{};

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  String HA1 = _computeHA1(realm, algorithm, username, password, nonce, cnonce);

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  String HA2;

  if (qop == 'auth-int') {
    final bodyHash = md5Hash(body);
    final token2 = "$method:$path:$bodyHash";
    HA2 = md5Hash(token2);
  } else {
    // qop in [null, auth]
    final token2 = "$method:$path";
    HA2 = md5Hash(token2);
  }

  final nonceCount = _formatNonceCount(nc);
  ret['username'] = username;
  ret['realm'] = realm;
  ret['nonce'] = nonce;
  ret['uri'] = path;
  ret['qop'] = qop;
  ret['nc'] = nonceCount;
  ret['cnonce'] = cnonce;
  if (opaque != null) {
    ret['opaque'] = opaque;
  }
  ret['algorithm'] = algorithm;

  if (qop == null) {
    final token3 = "$HA1:$nonce:$HA2";
    ret['response'] = md5Hash(token3);
  } else if (qop == 'auth' || qop == 'auth-int') {
    final token3 = "$HA1:$nonce:$nonceCount:$cnonce:$qop:$HA2";
    ret['response'] = md5Hash(token3);
  }

  return ret;
}

class DigestAuth {
  DigestAuth(this.username, this.password);

  String username;
  String password;

  // must get from first response
  String _algorithm;
  String _qop;
  String _realm;
  String _nonce;
  String _opaque;

  int _nc = 0; // request counter
  String _cnonce; // client-generated; should change for each request

  String _computeNonce() {
    math.Random rnd = math.Random();

    List<int> values = List<int>.generate(16, (i) => rnd.nextInt(256));

    return hex.encode(values);
  }

  String getAuthString(String method, Uri url) {
    _cnonce = _computeNonce();
    _nc += 1;
    // if url has query parameters, append query to path
    var path = url.hasQuery ? "${url.path}?${url.query}" : url.path;

    // after the first request we have the nonce, so we can provide credentials
    var authValues = computeResponse(method, path, '', _algorithm, _qop,
        _opaque, _realm, _cnonce, _nonce, _nc, username, password);
    final authValuesString = authValues.entries
        .where((e) => e.value != null)
        .map((e) => [e.key, '="', e.value, '"'].join(''))
        .toList()
        .join(', ');
    final authString = 'Digest $authValuesString';
    return authString;
  }

  void initFromAuthorizationHeader(String authInfo) {
    Map<String, String> values = splitAuthenticateHeader(authInfo);
    _algorithm = values['algorithm'];
    _qop = values['qop'];
    _realm = values['realm'];
    _nonce = values['nonce'];
    _opaque = values['opaque'];
  }

  bool isReady() {
    return _nonce != null;
  }
}
```

Then when calling your api

```
final response =
          await DigestAuthClient(DIGEST_AUTH_USERNAME, DIGEST_AUTH_PASSWORD)
              .post(LOGIN_URL, body: {
        "USERNAME": userName,
        "PASSWORD": password,
        "USER_GROUP": "2"
      }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 20));
```

All credit goes to the following library https://pub.dev/packages/http_auth