# Digest Authentication not working with HttpClient

Tags: flutter

I have used all approaches to Post data using digest authentication but it is not working?
`HttpClient authenticatingClient = HttpClient(); authenticatingClient.addCredentials( Uri.parse( 'http://202.142.0000', ), 'aa',=>realm HttpClientDigestCredentials('admin', 'admin'), ); clients = https.IOClient(authenticatingClient); clients .post( Uri.parse( 'http://202.142.0000', ), headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body: json.encode({ "Protocol": "a[enter image description here][1]", "Packets": [ { "Id": 1, "Type": "PumpGetStatus", "Data": {"Pump": 1} } ] }), ) .then((value) { print(value.headers); });`

Comment: Please update the question to show the code you've already tried.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022844/flutter-how-to-implement-digest-authentification and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59442714/how-to-make-digest-authentication-with-http-in-flutter

Comment: // var client = http_auth.DigestAuthClient('admin', 'admin');clients
        .post(
      Uri.parse(
        'http://202.000.00.00/'
      ),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: json.encode({
        "Protocol": "o",
        "Packets": [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Type": "PumpGetStatus",
            "Data": {"Pump": 1}
          }
        ]
      }),
    )
        .then((value) {
      print(value.headers);
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and report the results.

You'll be aiming for the code shown in `main` (which uses pre-authentication, as long as you know the realm in advance). Somehow, I'm guessing that `aa` isn't the valid realm.

The code in `main2` can be substituted temporarily. Even though it will definitely fail, it will print out the realm, etc. to confirm the true values.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/io_client.dart' as ioc;

void main() async {
  final postMap = {
    'Protocol': 'o',
    'Packets': [
      {
        'Id': 1,
        'Type': 'PumpGetStatus',
        'Data': {'Pump': 1}
      }
    ]
  };
  final uri = Uri.parse('http://202.142.x.x');
  final authenticatingClient = HttpClient();
  authenticatingClient.addCredentials(
    uri,
    'aa', // is this actually the realm, or is it a guess?
    HttpClientDigestCredentials('admin', 'admin'),
  );
  http.Client client = ioc.IOClient(authenticatingClient);

  final response = await client.post(
    uri,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: json.encode(postMap),
  );

  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);

  client.close();
}

void main2() async {
  final postMap = {
    'Protocol': 'o',
    'Packets': [
      {
        'Id': 1,
        'Type': 'PumpGetStatus',
        'Data': {'Pump': 1}
      }
    ]
  };
  final uri = Uri.parse('http://202.142.x.x');
  final authenticatingClient = HttpClient();
  authenticatingClient.authenticate = ((u, s, r) async {
    print('uri=$u scheme=$s realm=$r');
    return false;
  });
  http.Client client = ioc.IOClient(authenticatingClient);

  final response = await client.post(
    uri,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: json.encode(postMap),
  );

  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);

  client.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is not valid realm , I am getting realm but iam not getting status 200

Comment: You need to put a valid realm in there. Use the `main2` supplied above (rename it to `main`) and see what that prints.

Comment: Why I need to put valid realm , when I am getting realm from authentication

Comment: Connection closed before full header was received
E/flutter (18685): #0      IOClient.send
package:http/src/io_client.dart:61 getting this after passing realm valid

Comment: Feels like you need to grab a packet capture.